# How To Choose Subsets To Form A Matrix Of Combinations

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, combinatorics, backtracking

I have created (after a few months of learning VBA and then switching to Python) a script that will backtrack and select the combinations of a number, n, in an order that is equivalent to the combinations of n of a higher selection, k.

Or another way of saying it: I create a matrix of 5 supersets by doing 5C4. I create a list of 10 subsets by doing 5C2. I then use backtracking to choose each subset to form the supersets.

Example using [A, B, C, D, E]:

5C4 = 5 supersets -> [ABCD,
ABCE,
ABDE,
ACDE,
BCDE]

Likewise, 5C2 = 10 subsets -> [AB,
AC,
AD,
AE,
BC,
BD,
BE,
CD,
CE,
DE]

Finally, 5(subsets)*2(groups)=10(supersets) results into something like:

```
[[(A, B), (C, D)]
 [(A, C), (D, E)]
 [(A, D), (B, E)]
 [(A, E), (B, C)]
 [(B, D), (C, E)]]
```

- granted there are a few different matrix solutions that could arise based on the order you have the list of 5C2.. but I have spent way toooo much time on figuring out the correct/general way of doing this, which seems like unnecessary information. I have also gone down the rabbit hole of making sure that I can arrange the subsets in a way that each element of `result[row][col][element]` appears in the col a specific number of times. And after I find a faster way of selecting subsets, I will reorder them to do this (as a bonus if anyone knows how to do this; I am thinking permutations). Did you know that you can get occurrence of each element from Pascal's triangle... But I digress.

Backtracking works for smaller numbers, but if I do something larger, let's say `17C15(superset) = 17C3(subset)*5(groups)`, the code runs too long (stopping it after +40h).

In these examples here is the logic of why I think this should work:

```
5C2 = 10
5C4 =  5
5C4 * 2(groups) = 10

17C3  = 680
17C15 = 136
17C15 * 5(groups) = 680
```

1.) Is my logic correct? I considered that when choosing an `n`, `k_1 < (n/2), k_2 > (n/2), and k_1|k_2 (k_2 is a multiple of k_1)`.

2.) If this is the most practical way of choosing subsets, then can anyone help optimize my code?

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

families = range(1, 6)
choose = 2
groups = 2
size = int(choose*groups)
teams = list(combinations(families, choose))
cluster = list(combinations(families, size)) 
team_len = int(len(teams)/groups) 
zero_set = [(0) for _ in range(choose)]

def check(grid, row, column, subset):
    # check if combo(subset) is a subset of cluster's row
    if ((set(subset) & set(cluster[row])) != set(subset)):
        return False
    check = set(x for x in chain(*grid[row]))
    if(set(tuple(x) for x in grid[row]).intersection(set(subset))):
        return False
    if(check.intersection(set(subset))):
        return False
    for x in range(team_len):
        for y in range(groups):
            # check if used already
            if (grid[x][y] == subset):
                return False
    return True

def solve(grid, row, column):
    if(row == team_len and column == groups - 1): return True
    if(row == team_len):  
        column += 1
        row = 0

    if grid[row][column] > zero_set:
        return solve(grid, row, column + 1)
    
    for subset in teams:
        if check(grid, row, column, subset):
            grid[row][column] = subset
            if solve(grid, row + 1, column):
                return True
        grid[row][column] = zero_set
    return False

grid = [[zero_set]*groups for _ in range(team_len)]
if solve(grid, 0, 0):
    print("success")
for x in grid:
    print(x)

print("finished")
```

This returns:

```
success
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
[(1, 3), (2, 5)]
[(1, 5), (2, 4)]
[(1, 4), (3, 5)]
[(2, 3), (4, 5)]
finished
```

Success criteria would be to have all 680 combinations used once (no repetitions) in the final matrix, grid.

```
families = range(1, 18)
choose = 3
groups = 5
```

Comment: You realize that the "groups of subsets" are not unique and that there are many possible sub-groupings to produce the superset, right?

Comment: @AirSquid I agree with your second part of the question. In fact there are "(groups*choose)Choose(choose)" combinations that could be used to create each superset. But for the first part, are you saying the "groups of subsets" are not unique if they are grouped like this: [(AB, CD), (AB, CE), (AB, DE), (AC, DE), (BC, DE)]? They are "not unique groups of subsets" because the groups have repeating subsets? If so, I had put in the original post subsets that do not repeat, such that they are "unique groups of subsets".

Answer (score 0):

For the general case of finding a matrix, the Cartesian Product of the columns giving every possible combination in the space S choose k of elements e:

Let column_height = S - k + 1;
Let width = k;

Assign an ordinal to every e. If the expected frequency of an element e is important from a resource perspective, arrange the ordinals in ascending frequency order.

Populate the matrix in this manner:

- the first column contains elements [1 to column_height]
- the second column elements [2 to column_height+1]
- etc.

In order to find the mapping of any combinatorial set, k:

- iterate down each column until you find e, a member of k.
- store the row and remove e from k
- repeat until the final column,  whereby k will be empty and you will have an integer sequence for the rows containing the member's of k.
- if these operations will be performed frequently, consider caching the <Set, List> map.

If you want a Java implementation of this, I can send you one over.

Will